# What's the typical scientific python optimization path?

Tags: python, numpy, hpc

This is maybe a fairly generic question, I'm trying to adapt a python based scientific computation code to executing in real time.  Right now, conservatively, a single threaded implementation executes about 1000 times too slow for real time processing.  But, I'm not sure what the next step is in boosting the performance.

I've already done the obvious things.  All the heavy lifting is done either with numpy array computations, or using modules built in Cython.  About 50% of the time is spent calculating FFT's and doing array multiplications, and the other 50% is spent in the Cython routines.  The Cython routines themselves aren't perfect, but they aren't too bad either.  I've also profiled the code to make sure that some other no so important routine isn't taking up more time than I think it is.

The good news is that the code is quite easily adapted to parallel processing.  I've actually already done this using python processes, and it scales almost linearly up to the number of CPU cores in the computer.  But, this only gets me about a factor of 20 speed increase or so.

So, where do I proceed from here?  Rewrite the code as a Python module in C, maybe directly using the Cpython API?  Completely abandon Python for some other language?  Try implementing the code using PyCUDA or openCL?  Something else entirely?

Comment: While this is not specific to scientific computing (the topic was business analytics for social gaming company IIRC), perhaps this video lecture might be of use: [How to Speed up a Python Program 114,000 times](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e08kOj2kISU)

Comment: Right now, the code has already been reduced to tight loops around either numpy functions, or around Cython modules.  Isn't this the usage case in which pypy is least likely to show gains.

Comment: Is your comment in response to another deleted comment?  Pypy isn't the main solution of David Schachter's presentation above

Comment: Yes, sorry.  I'm watching through the link you posted now.

Comment: So, if I followed the presentation correctly, right now I'm on about the same path David Schachtner followed.  I'm not quite so far along, but it's taking more and more work to get smaller and smaller improvements.  Are you suggesting that I should be able to get another factor of 50 speed improvement by just optimizing the compute kernel, even though I spend almost half the time running numpy.fft.fft?

Comment: I think the presentation gives you a typical speed-up path, so from numpy + Cython (you've got the low hanging fruits already), a general potential path is to hand-tune the Cython component.  An alternative route may be looking into [numba](http://numba.pydata.org) to speed up the numpy FFTs, if you haven't explored that avenue yet.

Comment: Well, I'll keep slogging through it then.  From this perspective, it may make sense to put the entire routine into cython.  We'll see how that works.  I also seen to test out some different fft implementations, it'd be nice to get those a little faster.

Comment: If you're spending a lot of time doing FFTs, I would recommend using [pyFFTW](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyFFTW). FFTW3 is quite a lot faster than numpy's built-in FFTPACK and supports multi-threading.

Comment: @zehnpaard numba won't speed up the FFTs in any appreciable way - numba's JIT compiler can only optimize Python code, whereas `np.fft.fft` spends almost all of its time in FFTPACK routines, which are written in Fortran.

Comment: @all_m I actually gave pyFFTW a quick try already.  Right now, I'm seeing it be faster for longish arrays (N>2048 or so), and slower for shorter arrays (N<512).  This is probably related to the overhead in creating the fft class.  I tried turning on caching, but didn't see much improvement.  This is a problem because I'm doing a lot of short FFTs, instead of a couple of long FFTs.

Comment: If you have a lot of small FFTs to do, could you vectorize them using `fftn(..., axes=(...))`? Also, FFTs will be faster if your array dimensions are powers of 2.

Comment: This is a great idea, not sure why I didn't think of it.  I'll give it a shot today and see if it gains me anything.

Comment: If your code is running on Linux and intel platform, you can try to recompile numpy and scipy to take advantage of MKL to accelerate FFT (there is non-commercial license of intel MKL available on Linux), see a [guide](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/numpyscipy-with-intel-mkl)

Comment: @all_m Ok, fftn sped things up about 40% for the FFT parts without too much work to implement.  Some restructuring and pre-computing got about a 60% improvement in the Cython portion.  That took a lot more work, and not everything I tried resulted in a speed improvement either.  Not bad, but not a 50x speed up either.

Comment: @cloudtex That's another great idea, since this will be running on exactly that platform.